# Procedure to INSERT query result inserts nothing even with the query passing values

Tags: mysql, insert, dynamic-sql

The query assigns values into `@suppliertaxid`, `@FT_totalvalue`, `@FT_taxablevalue`but they are not assigned to `supplytaxid`, `ft_totalvalue` 
 and `ft_taxablevalue` and/or written to the table by the `INSERT`

Please help!

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p_fill_totalfaturasporfornecedor`(in_tabelaefaturaaquisicoesFornecedor varchar(64)
, in_suppliertaxid varchar(20)
, in_tabelaMaioresAquisicoesFornecedor varchar(64))
BEGIN

    DECLARE suppliertaxid varchar(20);
    DECLARE FT_totalvalue decimal(13,2);
    DECLARE FT_taxablevalue decimal(13,2);
    DECLARE FT_VATvalue decimal(13,2);
    DECLARE NC_totalvalue decimal(13,2);
    DECLARE NC_taxablevalue decimal(13,2);
    DECLARE NC_VATvalue decimal(13,2);
    DECLARE totalvalue decimal(13,2);
    DECLARE taxablevalue decimal(13,2);
    DECLARE VATvalue decimal(13,2);
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING

    SET @v = concat('SELECT  suppliertaxid
                                , sum(totalvalue)
                                , sum(taxablevalue)
                                , sum(vatvalue) INTO @suppliertaxid, @FT_totalvalue, @FT_taxablevalue, @VATvalue 
                    FROM ',in_tabelaefaturaaquisicoesFornecedor,'
                    where invoicetype in (''FT'',''FR'',''FS'',''ND'',''VD'',''TV'',''OU'')
                    and invoicestatus like ''REGISTADA''
                    and suppliertaxid=',in_suppliertaxid,'
                    group by suppliertaxid  
                    order by sum(totalvalue) desc,  sum(taxablevalue) desc, sum(VATvalue) desc');

    PREPARE stm FROM @v;
    EXECUTE stm;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;

    set @insert_top_suppliers = concat('insert into ',in_tabelaMaioresAquisicoesFornecedor ,'(suppliertaxid
    , FT_totalvalue
    , FT_taxablevalue
    , FT_VATvalue
    , NC_totalvalue
    , NC_taxablevalue
    , NC_VATvalue
    , totalvalue
    , taxablevalue
    , VATvalue) 
    values
    (@suppliertaxid, @FT_totalvalue, @FT_taxablevalue, @FT_VATvalue,null,null,null,null,null,null');

    prepare stmt from @insert_top_suppliers;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;

END
```

No error messages, just does not insert the result and the table has no restrictions on fields

Comment: Why do you need `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` when you're just getting one row for a single `suppliertaxid`?

Comment: Because the table «in_tabelaefaturaaquisicoesFornecedor» can have one or more records for a suppliertaxid and i want to get  the sum of the values of totalvalue, taxablevalue and vatvalue

Comment: That's what `SUM()` does, it combines all the rows into a single result.

Comment: You only need `GROUP BY` if you're selecting multiple suppliers and you want a row for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Since `in_suppliertaxid` is a string, you need quotes around it.

But instead, you can set a session variable and refer to it in the SQL.

```
    SET @in_suppliertaxid = in_suppliertaxid;
    SET @v = concat('SELECT  suppliertaxid
                                , sum(totalvalue)
                                , sum(taxablevalue)
                                , sum(vatvalue) INTO @suppliertaxid, @FT_totalvalue, @FT_taxablevalue, @VATvalue 
                    FROM ',in_tabelaefaturaaquisicoesFornecedor,'
                    where invoicetype in (''FT'',''FR'',''FS'',''ND'',''VD'',''TV'',''OU'')
                    and invoicestatus like ''REGISTADA''
                    and suppliertaxid= @in_suppliertaxid');
```

There's also no need for `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. You're grouping by the same column that you're selecting in the `WHERE` clause, so there will only be one row.

In the `INSERT` query, you're missing the `)` at the end of the `VALUES` list.

```
    SET @v = concat('SELECT  suppliertaxid
                                , sum(totalvalue)
                                , sum(taxablevalue)
                                , sum(vatvalue) INTO @suppliertaxid, @FT_totalvalue, @FT_taxablevalue, @VATvalue 
                    FROM ',in_tabelaefaturaaquisicoesFornecedor,'
                    where invoicetype in (''FT'',''FR'',''FS'',''ND'',''VD'',''TV'',''OU'')
                    and invoicestatus like ''REGISTADA''
                    and suppliertaxid=',in_suppliertaxid,'
                    group by suppliertaxid  
                    order by sum(totalvalue) desc,  sum(taxablevalue) desc, sum(VATvalue) desc');

    PREPARE stm FROM @v;
    EXECUTE stm;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;

    set @insert_top_suppliers = concat('insert into ',in_tabelaMaioresAquisicoesFornecedor ,'(suppliertaxid
    , FT_totalvalue
    , FT_taxablevalue
    , FT_VATvalue
    , NC_totalvalue
    , NC_taxablevalue
    , NC_VATvalue
    , totalvalue
    , taxablevalue
    , VATvalue) 
    values
    (@suppliertaxid, @FT_totalvalue, @FT_taxablevalue, @FT_VATvalue,null,null,null,null,null,null)');
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use local variables in prepared statements like session variables.

Comment: OK, I've put back the concatenation and added the quotes.

Comment: You are right about all your remarks but still the table doesn't get the record inserted!

Comment: The original code should have reported an error because of the missing quotes. If you're running the procedure from a client language like PHP, make sure you've added error checking.

Comment: i forgot to remove the EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING and so it indeed gives an error Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12

Comment: Have you enabled the `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode?

Comment: Maybee i need to name the fields of the target table differently from the initial data table?

Comment: I've changed it to use ANSI quoting.

Comment: No ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode

Comment: Try the new answer, where I set a session variable to the parameter.

Comment: Also not running from a client program language, its just a database stored procedure

Comment: You missed the right parentesis  at the final of your new code as before, but still gives the same error at line 12 that i believe is DECLARE totalvalue decimal(13,2);

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong. Can you do `SELECT @suppliertaxid, @FT_totalvalue, @FT_taxablevalue, @VATvalue;` to see if it's getting anything in the first query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200093/discussion-between-antonio-manuel-paraiso-pinto-and-barmar).